# why can't skopeo inspect the local registry?

Tags: docker-registry, skopeo

I have the following images on RHEL7:

```
sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
localhost:5000/myrhel7                  latest              dc2f776f25d9        6 days ago          208 MB
registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/rhel   latest              dc2f776f25d9        6 days ago          208 MB
```

skopeo fails so:

```
sudo skopeo inspect  docker://localhost:5000/myrhel7
FATA[0000] Error parsing image name "docker://localhost:5000/myrhel7": error pinging docker registry localhost:5000: Get https://localhost:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Then, following the Red Hat documentation I prepended "http:":

```
sudo skopeo inspect  docker://http:localhost:5000/myrhel7
FATA[0000] Error parsing image name "docker://http:localhost:5000/myrhel7": invalid reference format
```

The same occurs prepending "http://" :

```
sudo skopeo inspect  docker://http://localhost:5000/myrhel7
FATA[0000] Error parsing image name "docker://http://localhost:5000/myrhel7": invalid reference format
```

So, Am I doing something wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skopeo supports this with an undocumented parameter `--tls-verify` (at least it's hidden from the `--help` output):

```
skopeo inspect --tls-verify=false  docker://localhost:5000/myrhel7
```

See [issue 459](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/issues/459) for the appropriate option on other commands.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch, so it's seems that RHEL7 documentation is wrong about it.